# How to delay events until several buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, jquery-events

In my project, I would like to delay events -- specifically going up or down a 'floor' or displaying the floor number -- until all the buttons of the elevator are pressed.

E.g., If I press 2, 4, 1, 3, the numbers should display in that order, and the up or down indicator should highlight as appropriate.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $buttons = $('.buttons'),
        $floorAnimate = $('.floor-animate'),
        $floorPanel = $('floor-panel'); 
 
  
  function pressButtons()
  {
    $('.floor-number').css('display', 'none');
     $buttons.click(function()
     {
        var $floorNumber = $(this).text(),
            floorOn = $('floor-number').text();
                
       $(this).addClass('pressed');
       $('.floor-number').css('display', 'block').append($floorNumber).animate({top: '-200px'}, 1500);
       $('#up-indicator').addClass('up');
     });
  }
      
  
   
 pressButtons();
});
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to *delay* events.  Every time somebody presses a button you should check if "all the buttons of the elevator are pressed."  Once they are, you can *trigger* the final event (call a function, trigger a click-event).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @HarryPehkonen you are correct; this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Harry I'm not sure if the events should be delayed. It's all I could think how to solve the problem. But ALL the buttons don't need to be pressed. A user could press 2, 4, 1, for example. Or just 1.

Comment: Well you need to use an array to queue the floors that you going to and track the elevator journey based on that.Please rephrase your question as it is very vague at the moment

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you'll need to slap each click event into an array and do a timed delay that handles what you want. I've done something rough that does this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fJcFo

I've added some console.logs so you can see what happens at each event.
But essentially what happens is:

- during the on click event, the html element text is put into an object under "queuedFloor".
- Inside of this object are two functions, one is button pressed, the other is at floor.
- The queued floor is then added to an array list called elevator.queue.
- what button pressed does is **settimeout 3 seconds** and then calls an alert to tell you you're at the floor, you could add your logic for when you are at the floor. It also calls the at floor function, which removes the object from elevator queue.

If you want more flexibility with your html object. you could pass in the whole Element to the queuedFloor object by adding this to it: **element:pressedItem**
Then when you want to reference the HTML element, you can call it by its object reference (elevator.queue[0].element) and do standard javascript manipulation such as:

```
elevator.queue[0].element.classList.add('onfloor');
```

which would add a class to that specific element called "onfloor".

Firstly I take create a javascript object:

```
 var elevator = elevator || {};
```

Then I add actions to my elevator object

```
 elevator.actions = {
buttonPressed:function(pressedItem){
  console.log(pressedItem);
  var queuedFloor = {
    floor: pressedItem.innerText;
    goToFloor: setTimeout(function(){
            alert("arrived at floor" + elevator.queue[0].floor); //do your html manipulation for item here, remember its async so have to reference it by its position in the queue. In this case we only ever call the item in position 0 of the array.
            elevator.queue[0].atFloor();
  }, 3000),
    atFloor: (function(){
     elevator.queue.splice(0, 1);
      console.log('queue spliced', elevator.queue);
    })

  };

  elevator.queue.push(queuedFloor);
elevator.actions.moveElevator();
}
moveElevator:function(){
  console.log('queued floors', elevator.queue);
elevator.queue[0].goToFloor();
}
```

};
  elevator.queue = []

Then I set up my click listener

```
  $buttons.click(function()
 {elevator.actions.buttonPressed(this)});
```

});

Comment: This is helpful. In your commented section, you say I should reference it by its position in the array. I'm confused about this part. How would I do that? In other words, instead of the alert, how do I hook up the display panel to show the number?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working, I liked your original solution better, but I just wanted to substitute the alert with some actual functionality, namely, the up/down buttons and the number display in the panel.